# Components in AJAX tab not showing up when switching tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, tabs

I am trying to hide and show AJAX tab panel with certain condition which I get from SQL. Let's say I got three tab, the first tab always there, the second tab showing only when it is not yet delivered whereas third tab showing only when it is delivered. Here is the method which I switch tab to get the tab index:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get distributionID based on URL
        distributionID = Request.QueryString["id"];

        //First tab to display beneficiary details
        beneficiaryIndv = packBLL.getBeneficiaryDetail(distributionID);

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            //Get the index of selected tab
            if (!(ViewState["TabIndex"] == null) && (!(sender == null)))
            {
                if (sender.GetType().ToString().Equals("AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer"))
                {
                    ((AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer)sender).ActiveTabIndex = (int)ViewState["TabIndex"];
                }
            }
        }

        //On page load to check the delivery status to determine which tab to hide
        string isDelivered = packBLL.checkIsDelivered(distributionID);
        if (isDelivered == "Y")
        {
            TabPanelSPU.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            TabPanelViewSPUItem.Visible = false;
        }
    }

protected void TabContainer_OnActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["TabIndex"] = TabContainer.ActiveTabIndex;

        if ((int)ViewState["TabIndex"] == 1)
        {
            //Get the list of standard packing unit by distribution
            List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits> SPUList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits>();
            SPUList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUByDistID(distributionID);
            gvSPU1.DataSource = SPUList;
            gvSPU1.DataBind();
        }
        else if ((int)ViewState["TabIndex"] == 2)
        {
            //Get the list of standard packing unit by distribution
            List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits> SPUList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits>();
            SPUList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUByDistID(distributionID);
            gvSPU.DataSource = SPUList;
            gvSPU.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

However, when the delivery status is delivered, it hides the second tab. But the components inside third tab is not showing. I wonder is it because of the if else statement in tab on active change method causing this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

                        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"
                            OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainer_OnActiveTabChanged" AutoPostBack="true">

                            <!--FIRST TAB -->
                            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanelBeneficiary" runat="server" HeaderText="Beneficiary" CssClass="ajax__tab_tab">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <h3 class="form-section">Person Info</h3>

                                    <h3 class="form-section">Address</h3>

                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:TabPanel>

                            <!--SECOND TAB -->
                            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanelSPU" runat="server" HeaderText="Standard Packing" CssClass="ajax__tab_tab">
                                <ContentTemplate>

                                 </ContentTemplate>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                                                        </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:TabPanel>

                            <!--THIRD TAB -->
                            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanelViewSPUItem" runat="server" HeaderText="Distributed Packing Items" CssClass="ajax__tab_tab">
                                <ContentTemplate>

                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:TabPanel>
```

Comment: Please confirm the condition: if it's delivered, then hide second tab and display third tab; if it's not delivered, then display second tab and hide third tab?

Comment: Yeah, it supposed to work that way. Because my viewState is getting the tabIndex 2 which mean third tab, when I hide the second tab, it shows nothing inside the tab

Comment: Is `gvSPU1` inside `TabPanelSPU` and `gvSPU` inside `TabPanelViewSPUItem`?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for did not post the components inside tab as it exceeds the word limit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `TabContainer.ActiveTabIndex` will skip the hidden tab(s). If you set `TabPanelSPU.Visible` to false, then when you click on `TabPanelViewSPUItem` (the third tab) the value of `TabContainer.ActiveTabIndex` will be 1 instead of 2. That explains why the components inside the third tab is not showing.

I'd suggest checking `TabPanelSPU.Visible` and `TabPanelViewSPUItem.Visible` instead

```
protected void TabContainer_OnActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TabPanelSPU.Visible)
    {
        //Get the list of standard packing unit by distribution
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits> SPUList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits>();
        SPUList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUByDistID(distributionID);
        gvSPU1.DataSource = SPUList;
        gvSPU1.DataBind();
    }

    if (TabPanelViewSPUItem.Visible)
    {
        //Get the list of standard packing unit by distribution
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits> SPUList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnits>();
        SPUList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUByDistID(distributionID);
        gvSPU.DataSource = SPUList;
        gvSPU.DataBind();
    }
}
```

You'll also need to remove this portion of code in `Page_Load` since it's not needed.

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    //Get the index of selected tab
    if (!(ViewState["TabIndex"] == null) && (!(sender == null)))
    {
        if (sender.GetType().ToString().Equals("AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer"))
        {
            ((AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer)sender).ActiveTabIndex = (int)ViewState["TabIndex"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. The third tab shows up with nothing if I set the visibility of second tab to false.

Comment: I removed the IsPostBack from pageLoad and put in the code above but it does not work as well :(

Comment: Can you try to set a break point inside `TabContainer_OnActiveTabChanged` and see what happens when you click on the third tab?

Comment: What I meant was deleting the `if (IsPostBack)` and its content, see the edited answer.

Comment: It did goes into the if statement, just that nothing is coming up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46690/discussion-between-ekad-and-gwen)